# How can I change my class PDO for correct work

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I've rewritten the connection to database from mysqli to PDO. My connection works with prepared statements. My class PDO look like that:

```
  <?php

define('DB_HOST', 'xxx');
define('DB_NAME', 'xxx');
define('DB_USER', 'xxx');
define('DB_PASS', 'xxx');
define('DB_CHAR', 'xxx');

class DBController
{
    protected static $instance;
    protected $pdo;

    public function __construct() {
        $opt  = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => FALSE,
        );
        $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset='.DB_CHAR;
        $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $opt);

    }

    // a classical static method to make it universally available
    public static function instance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null)
        {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    // a proxy to native PDO methods
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->pdo, $method), $args);
    }

    // a helper function to run prepared statements smoothly
    public function run($sql, $args = [])
    {
        if (!$args)
        {
            return $this->query($sql);
        }
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
    function insert($query) {
        if (!$args)
        {
            return $this->query($sql);
        }
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }

    function update($query) {
        if (!$args)
        {
            return $this->query($sql);
        }
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

The connection to database with new class PDO works clearly. But, when I want to login as an user I've got an 'Invalid Login'. However, login and password has been correct.

My class Auth look like that:

```
       <?php
require "DBController.class.php";

class Auth {

    protected $db;

    protected $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = DBController::instance();
    }

        function getMemberByUsername($username)
    {
        $this->data = $this->db->run("Select * from `members` where `member_name` = ?", array($username))->fetchAll(0);
    }


    function getTokenByUsername($username,$expired)
    {
        $this->data = $this->db->run("Select * from `tbl_token_auth` where `username` = ? and `is_expired` = ?", [$username, $expired])->fetchAll();
    }

    function markAsExpired($tokenId)
    {
        $expired = 1;
        $this->data = $this->db->run("UPDATE `tbl_token_auth` SET `is_expired` = ? WHERE id = ?", [$expired, $tokenId])->fetchAll();
    }

    function insertToken($username, $random_password_hash, $random_selector_hash, $expiry_date)
    {
        $this->data = $this->db->run("INSERT INTO `tbl_token_auth` (username, password_hash, selector_hash, expiry_date) values (?, ?, ?,?)", [$username, $random_password_hash, $random_selector_hash, $expiry_date])->fetchAll();
    }

}
```

Below the code, which works with function getMemberByUsername

```
if (! empty($_POST["login"])) {
$isAuthenticated = false;

$username = $_POST["member_name"];
$password = $_POST["member_password"];

$user = $auth->getMemberByUsername($username);
if (password_verify($password, $user[0]->member_password)) {
    $isAuthenticated = true;
}
if ($isAuthenticated) {
    $_SESSION["member_id"] = $user[0]["member_id"];

    // Set Auth Cookies if 'Remember Me' checked
    if (! empty($_POST["remember"])) {
        setcookie("member_login", $username, $cookie_expiration_time);

        $random_password = $util->getToken(16);
        setcookie("random_password", $random_password, $cookie_expiration_time);

        $random_selector = $util->getToken(32);
        setcookie("random_selector", $random_selector, $cookie_expiration_time);

        $random_password_hash = password_hash($random_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $random_selector_hash = password_hash($random_selector, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $expiry_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $cookie_expiration_time);

        // mark existing token as expired
        $userToken = $auth->getTokenByUsername($username, 0);
        if (! empty($userToken[0]["id"])) {
            $auth->markAsExpired($userToken[0]["id"]);
        }
        // Insert new token
        $auth->insertToken($username, $random_password_hash, $random_selector_hash, $expiry_date);
    } else {
        $util->clearAuthCookie();
    }
    $util->redirect("dashboard.php");
} else {
    $message = "Invalid Login";
}
```

}

What I did wrong?

Comment: Your `insert()` and `update()` methods use `if (!$args)` but neither accepts `$args` as a function parameter as `run()` does.

Comment: I've added $args to function insert() and update()

Comment: Are you sure the record with such username exists in the DB? Maybe the values are padded with whitespace?

Comment: I sure. I was trying to login with another user, but I saw same situation.  May be the problem in the checking user in talken. I added this code.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `O::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ`, so `fetchAll()` returns an array of objects, not arrays. So you need to use `$user[0]->member_password` to get the password from the result.

```
if (password_verify($password, $user[0]->member_password)) {
    $isAuthenticated = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've corrected, but still see "Invalid Login"

Comment: Why do you have `0` in `fetchAll(0)`?

Comment: 0 - it's a mistake. I've deleted it. 

var_dump($username);    
shows  -- string(5) "andre" 

var_dump($user);    
shows  -- NULL